# Filter processes in Go

Tags: linux, go

I have a Go script that takes user input from the config file and executes a command like this `ps -ef | grep <USER_INPUT>`. The purpose of this script is to collect application monitoring information from the java processes. In order to collect this information, the user needs to tell the go script from which processes they want to collect this information.

In the current implementation, if I pass input `java` as user input then the script is executing  `ps -ef | grep java` command and returning all processes where the word `java` matches. Next, the script is collecting monitoring information from all these processes.

Now I want to enhance the logic to achieve the below scenario:

- Find processes with the given username
- Find processes where a particular word matches
- Ignore processes where a particular word matches

Let's say I have the following 4 processes running on my server:

```
user1  2683  1  0 Dec03 ?        00:06:28 java -Xms2g -Xmx48g -DlogDir=. -DuploadDir=. -jar webapp-runner-8.0.33.4.jar -AconnectionTimeout=3600000 --port 8080 app1.war
user2 26568  1  1 06:32 pts/3    00:00:32 java -Xms2g -Xmx12g -DlogDir=. -DuploadDir=. -jar webapp-runner-9.0.31.0.jar -AconnectionTimeout=3600000 --port 9010 app2.war
user3 89568  1  1 06:32 pts/3    00:00:28 java -Xms2g -Xmx12g -DlogDir=. -DuploadDir=. -jar webapp-runner-9.0.31.0.jar -AconnectionTimeout=3600000 --port 9020 app3.war
user2 12657  1 22 Nov21 ?        1-05:51:45 java -Xmx1g -jar entrypoint.jar MS_ENV=dev MS_NAME=dev-cron MS_ID= MS_CLASS=com.test.cron.Cron
```

Now say from the above processes, I want to collect monitoring information from the processes that are owned by a user `user2` and `user3`, from the processes where the word `java` matches, and ignore processes where word `cron` matches.

The output should be:

```
user2 26568  1  1 06:32 pts/3    00:00:32 java -Xms2g -Xmx12g -DlogDir=. -DuploadDir=. -jar webapp-runner-9.0.31.0.jar -AconnectionTimeout=3600000 --port 9010 app2.war
user3 89568  1  1 06:32 pts/3    00:00:28 java -Xms2g -Xmx12g -DlogDir=. -DuploadDir=. -jar webapp-runner-9.0.31.0.jar -AconnectionTimeout=3600000 --port 9020 app3.war
```

Is it possible to pass regex or any other command as user input to achieve this? Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Passing user input to a command line tool is a [big security no-no](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection) of the user is not trused. You are better of by calling `ps -ef` (statically not with user input), and then applying a regex yourself using the [regexp](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp) library.

Alternatively, if you are writing a Go program anyway, you might consider getting the data you need directly from `/proc`, or use a library like [go-ps](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-ps). This saves you having to parse output that is meant for humans and directly get computer readable data. (However this depends on you usecase)

Comment: How is this a big no no? In pretty much 100% of cases, the owner of the machine is invoking the CLI. If they want to perform malicious actions on their own system, then they can do that all day long. Also note that most CLI tools out there take some form of user input. Think of grep, awk, cat, curl, etc. Are they all wrong? Otherwise, they would be little useful. I guess you are taking about using unkown input from some other user. Well in that case, you are right. Its probably not a good idea. But I dont read OPs question like that.

Comment: You are right, if the user of the app is fully trusted this is not an issue. I edited the answer to be more nuanced. However I believe in airing on of caution since I can't judge exactly how the application is used. I don't see any downside to using the regexp while there is a downside to passing user input to the CLI in certain situations. I put the info out there so anyone can make an informed decision.

Comment: Hi @caveman, The app (go script) will be running in the user's environment. The purpose of the script is to collect application monitoring information from the java processes. In order to do this, the user needs to tell the go script from which processes they want to collect this information.